# Server stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk" when using NVidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, initrd

I have a server with an NVidia M4000 Quaddro card. In my server BIOS, if I set the GPU priority to 'onboard', my system boots and I can use the NVidia card. If I set the GPU priority to 'external', my Linux boot hangs at 'Loading inital ramdisk'.

I've tried adding various debug levels to the GRUB command, as well as setting nomodeset, nofb, but nothing changes it hanging at that spot.

Answer (score 1):

The picture is moved from one port to another sometimes when the machine is booting, this happened to me with CentOS 7 where the picture was first shown at the VGA port and then later jumped to the display port.

Might not the be solution but its worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by updating the kernel. I was on a couple variants from 3.16-3.19, but after updating to 4.2+ it would boot normally.